# Checking parent's preceding siblings XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

Given:

```
<pm>
    <content>
        <pmEntry>
            <pmEntryTitle>Test</pmEntryTitle>
            <dmRef>
                <dmRefIdent>
                    <dmCode infoCode="100" infoCodeVariant="A" />
                </dmRefIdent>
            </dmRef>
        </pmEntry>
        <pmEntry>
            <pmEntryTitle>Test2</pmEntryTitle>
            <dmRef>
                <dmRefIdent>
                    <dmCode infoCode="200" infoCodeVariant="A" />
                </dmRefIdent>
            </dmRef>
        </pmEntry>
        <pmEntry>
            <pmEntryTitle>Test3</pmEntryTitle>
            <dmRef>
                <dmRefIdent>
                    <dmCode infoCode="300" infoCodeVariant="A" />
                </dmRefIdent>
            </dmRef>
        </pmEntry>
    </content>
</pm>
```

I want to call the Table of Contents template from the first `<dmRef>` in the first `<pmEntry>`

But this is not giving the expected output, it's sometimes calling the TOC again from the middle of the list of pmEntry as well as from the first pmEntry.

```
<xsl:if test="ancestor::content[count(pmEntry) > 1]/pmEntry and count(../preceding-sibling::pmEntry) = 0">
    <xsl:call-template name="contents" />
</xsl:if>
```

I don't understand why `count(../preceding-sibling::pmEntry)` is returning 0 in the middle of the list of pmEntries.

Any help or suggestions are always appreciated.

This is the complete template:

```
 <xsl:template match="pmEntry/dmRef">
               <!-- Front Matter template infocode = 001 before TOC-->
  <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ancestor::content/pmEntry/dmRef/dmRefIdent/dmCode[@infoCode='001']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <xsl:if test="dmRefIdent/dmCode/@infoCode='001'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="contents" />
                        <xsl:call-template name="figlist" >
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                    <!--Only one pmEntry, at first dmRef create TOC -->
                        <xsl:when test="ancestor::content[count(pmEntry) = 1]/pmEntry and count(preceding-sibling::dmRef) = 0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="contents" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="figlist" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <!--Multiple pmEntry, at first create TOC -->
                        <xsl:when test="count(../preceding-sibling::pmEntry)=0 and count(../preceding-sibling::dmRef)=0">
                            <xsl:call-template name="contents" />
                            <xsl:call-template name="figlist" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise />
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>       
           </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  If it's not what you want, give us an idea of your output.

```
<xsl:template match="dmRef">
  <xsl:if test="count(../preceding-sibling::pmEntry)=0 and count(preceding-sibling::dmRef)=0">
    <xsl:call-template name="contents" />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your suggestion and I'm still getting two TOCs, one in the beginning as desired and one in the middle. Desired output is just getting rid of that extraneous TOC.

Comment: I changed it to `<xsl:if test="count(../preceding-sibling::pmEntry)=0 and count(../preceding-sibling::dmRef)=0">` and that got rid of the extra TOC but the logic doesn't seem right.

Comment: So, what I posted is just a code fragment to get you started.  You probably need some form of the identity function also.  Can you post your code,  and a mock up of the XML your are expecting?

Comment: I'm not sure what XML to post, this is an XSL-FO project and I'm using Antenna House to view the pdf output. The FO tree?

Comment: Without knowing what the output should look like, I won't be able to help you.  Let me know, if you want me to delete my answer.  Then maybe someone else will come along and help you.

Comment: Thank you, you did help me, the TOC is only being called once now.